# How to use javascript control tab page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I created 2 pages. One is called `home.html`, which links to `products.html`. When I test this, I open `home.html`, and follow the link to `products.html`. But the javascript in `products.html` doesn't work (see code below).

This is `products.html`:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>
            page1
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        Content1</div>
    <div data-id="PersistentFooter" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#page1" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page2">Two</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page3">Three</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- end page1-->

<div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>
            page2
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        Content2</div>
    <div data-id="PersistentFooter" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#page1">One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page2" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Two</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page3">Three</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- end page2-->

<div data-role="page" id="page3">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>
            page3
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        Content3</div>
    <div data-id="PersistentFooter" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#page1">One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page2">Two</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page3" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Three</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- end page3-->
```

A working fiddle is now available at http://jsfiddle.net/JkYSa/, thanks to user ali-carikcioglu.

Can someone explain to me why this isn't working?

Comment: where are your css and jquery codes?

Comment: I use jquery. Can you help me to create tabs page contronl use javascript?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JkYSa/   is this live demo of your website?

Comment: you dont even bother to create a jsfiddle demo for this? I give you -1 for this.

Comment: This is home.html:http://jsfiddle.net/pborreli/pJgyu/
and This is products.html :http://jsfiddle.net/pborreli/pJgyu/

Comment: and i want to use javascript control page, can you help me?

Comment: @BấtKần look into [jquery tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/)

Comment: @woofmeow: I knew it, this is used only page include three 3 tabs, but I want to use javscript page one, page one? sorry my English.

Comment: Your JS file should be placed either in _hone.html_ head tag or inside _products.html_ body tag. Closing this question as a duplicate is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of things you are using jQuery Mobile in products.html. Since the fiddles you have posted are both pointing to the same thing and there is no proper html/js in there i can only assume the problem you are having is that you have not pointed products.html to the jQuery and jQuery mobile source.

add this to your head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-mobile/getting-started/
may be a good place to look at learning how to use the framework